# "Years of experience" in Careers 2.0 header not adding up

Tags: bug, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does it say I have 0 year of Java experience?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80390/why-does-it-say-i-have-0-year-of-java-experience)

I've made sure that I've used the same "asp.net" and "sharepoint" tag for all my relevant experience, but even thought those two far & away outpace my experience for any other tag, they don't even show up in the header.

[The profile in question is here.](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/greg-hurlman)

Comment: Realated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80390/why-does-it-say-i-have-0-year-of-java-experience