# Why does it say I have 0 year of Java experience?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I'm looking at the [new view on careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/justin), and I found what I think is a bug.

It says I have 0 year of Java experience.
[image: 0 Year of exp]

Comment: Yup - it's a known issue affecting experience calculations, apologies. We're working on it and will update once fixed.

Comment: Maybe you need to take some java training

Comment: @squillman, don't tell my boss!

Comment: @jjn Your secret's safe :)

Comment: yeowch!  It says I only have 3 years of C.  That's off by an order of magnitude...

Comment: @Polly, maybe that is an accurate measurement of our relative skill level.  `:P`

Comment: @jjnguy Oh, well if that's the case then it's off by *two* orders of magnitude.  ;-D

Comment: I on the other hand apparently have 10 (!) years of C# experience. Thats funny given the availability of the C# compiler 9 years ago.

Comment: 0 **year**? Duplicate of [viewed 1 times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times)

Comment: @Andrew, I suppose it should be `0 years` (assuming that the `0` was correct.)

Answer (score 8):

This has been fixed.  However, we just made the decision to remove the whole section until we have time to add full controls for showing / hiding / editing each piece.